# Passing a parameter to jQuery function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This looks very simple but I have little experience with jQuery and I can't wrap my head around it.

Let's say I have a dynamically generated HTML table, and in each row of this table is a link:

```
<a id='edit'>Edit User</a>
```

Now, the link should call a function with each user's ID as a parameter. I could do that inline liek this:

```
<a id='edit' onClick='editUser(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)'>Edit User</a>
```

But how do I do this in jQuery?

I can call the function like this:

```
$('a#edit').click(function () {
      editUser()
      return false;
    });
```

But how do I pass the ID to this function? I know I could first stick it into a hidden field and then get it from there by element id, but surely there's a better way?

I realize all the links would have the same id this way, so should I dynamically create the link ids by appending the user id? But then how do I call the jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ids must be unique throughout the entire HTML. So you could use a class selector and HTML5 data-* attribute:

```
<a class="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit User</a>
```

and then:

```
$('a.edit').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // do something with the id
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `data-*` attributes to pass parameters.

```
<a class='edit' data-id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Edit User</a>

$('a.edit').click(function () {
   editUser($(this).data("id"));
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning that data-id is HTML5 only.  If you use it with an HTML4 DOCTYPE, you're going to get validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Curt mentionned, the `data-id` is the way to go, if you're using HTML5. If you're using HTML4, I would pass this in the ID of the link :

`<a id='edit-321' class='edit'>Edit User</a>`

Then you can do this (and use `event.preventDefault()` rather than `return false` !) :

```
$('a.edit').click(function (evt) {
   editUser($(this).attr("id").substring(5));
   evt.preventDefault();
});
```